# Is there any way to display duplicate column value once in multiple rows in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have been trying to research and Google forever for this but I cannot find an answer. I have duplicate values in 1 column but I would like to display them only once. Is it even possible in SQL?

What I have:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 3 |
| A | 2 | 4 |
| B | 4 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 4 |
| C | 3 | 9 |

What I would like:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 3 |
| A |  | 4 |
| B | 4 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 4 |
| C |  | 9 |

Comment: It is possible, but formatting a result like that is much better done when _displaying_ the result in your application. SQL wasn't intended as a fancy report generator.

Comment: What database is it coming from

Comment: Thanks! Would you know whether it is possible in Power BI?

Comment: I believe it is MSSQL

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are **two** links to the **same** external image, and the question asker believes het is using MSSQL. A little more  info would be needed for anyone to give a serious answer.

Comment: oddly, OP had a quality table, then replaced it with the image links. Rolled back to a better version which is clear.

Comment: Sorry first time asking a question. The tables appeared messy when I refreshed so I tried editing the question again with pictures. I think it was rolled back to the original post

Comment: No worries @packchu =) If the answer below helped you, feel free to upvote it and mark it as the answer. And for the future, [avoid putting code or text in images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT A,
CASE WHEN (LAG(B) OVER (ORDER A)) = B THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,B) END AS B,
C FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks it worked beautifully! I had to edit it a bit but worked when I did CASE WHEN (LAG(B) OVER (ORDER BY A)) = B THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,B) END AS B,